# Multiplying two arrays in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply two arrays using fortran, the following is my code

```
program multiplyarray
    implicit none
! Declare Variables
    integer, dimension(2,3 :: first_array
    integer, dimension(3,2) ::second_array
    integer, dimension(2,2) :: resultant_array
    integer:: i, j, a, b, k, product


! Generating values for array
    a = 2
    do i = 1,2
        do j = 1,3

        first_array(i,j) = a
        a = a + 2
        end do
    end do

   print*,first_array

    do i = 1,3
        do j = 1,2

            b = 0
            second_array(i,j) = b
            b = b + 3
        end do
    end do

! Multiplying both arrays
        do i = 1,2
            do j = 1,2
                do k = 1,3
                   product = product + first_array(i,k) * second_array(k,j)
                end do
                    resultant_array (j,i) = product
            end do
        end do

! Displaying the resultant matrix
        do i = 1,2
            do j = 1,2
                    print *,resultant_array(i,j)
            end do
        end do

end program multiplyarray
```

What could be the error? I do not get the individual matrices so that i can multiply them to get the resultant matrix. The first matrix is 0 while the result of the second matrix is also 0

Comment: What happens? What are your results? Any error messages? Which error messages?

Comment: you need to initialize `product`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using matmul function

matmul (first_array, second_array) = resultant_array
Print*, resultant_array

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment? It is not a valid code.

Comment: But it is not valid Fortran.

Answer (score 4):

The second array will always be zero

```
    b = 0
    second_array(i,j) = b
    b = b + 3
```

you always set `b` to be zero. The line `b = b + 3` has no effect because `b` is always set to zero anyway.

When `second_array` is zero, the product will also be zero.

---

As HighPerformanceMark suggests, you can easily multiply two matrices using `matmul` or less easily but quickly using the BLAS library.

```
result = matmul(first_array, second_array)
```

Comment: Did you provide an answer to my question this morning?  I got the notification and saw the answer, but now it seems to have disappeared and I cannot access it.  Did you delete it or is the problem on my end?  If not, could you post the answer again?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Integrals Yes, I deleted it. I made a mistake.

Comment: Oh I see okay, BTW your code with a mistake is probably still light years better than my correct code, the way you organize/structure code is still very helpful to me. Thanks for the help anyways!